# Filter a table by column name in sas enterprise guide

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

How to use a column as a filter for a table in sas enterprise guide?

Example:
Got a column consisting of personal IDs and want that column as a filter on my table with information about ALOT of people.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: `Query Builder` is your friend in those situations. You should take a look in the [official documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/guide/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what version of SAS EG you are using, but here are the screenshots for SAS EG 5.1

1. start building a basic filter in query wizard
2. click on the drop down triangle for the filter value
3. select "columns" tab
4. select the actual column
5. make sure "Enclose values in quotes" is not ticked
6. Hit finish

[image]